# How to force Tor to connect through a bridge

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, bridge

I understand how to configure the torrc config file in order to access internet through Tor bridges.

But the scenario is such even though my ISP allows Tor traffic I still do not want my ISP to **easily** know I am using Tor. i.e. through IPs I’m connecting to that belong to directory authorities, Tor Relays and other Tor services.

I do not mind my ISP suspecting of the ports used by me as long as traffic is not decryptable by them.

I want to force Tor running on my computer to send data i use through Tor browser via the Tor bridge and the bridge only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we add a Tor Bridge all Tor connections and data are sent through that bridge and that bridge only. I found this answer by emailing tor.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you are looking for is to setup bridges and then block access to Directory authorities and/or other IP addresses in some manner in your system. This will force directory authorities and/or other IP addresses to connect via bridges. An example of how to block access to directory authorities and/or other IP addresses may be found in this question and answer: [Host List Blocking](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/host-list-blocking)

Comment: thank you, in order to do so, I need to have all IPs of Tor entry nodes in the world and also all IPs of directory servers. How do I find a complete list of them to block them in the host file? even though I find them, I will still need to keep on updating them throghout time, I feel like its hassle and also dangerous. 

Isnt there a more direct and a permanent way?

Comment: @QwertyCoolGuy Dear QwertyCoolGuy, This is a public information. For example you may find them using: https://atlas.torproject.org/ or http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ and you may dirctly link them to your system to update before each Tor connection.

Comment: There maybe other ways. Let us wait and see if one publishes them.

Comment: I am really looking forward too.